# How to integrate Main call flow with service now inbound flow in Amazon connect

Tags: servicenow, amazon-connect, servicenow-client-scripts, contact-center

Please help me

**Use case** : I have main call flow(IVR) , in that 3 options are there.
AND
I have a service now inbound flow which is exported from service now and imported to Amazon connect.

**Challenge**: phone number connected to main call flow. Whenever the customer calling, main call flow triggered.

From this how the same call routed to service now.

Please help

Thank you in advance